# PHP/MySQL: Order artist by ASC, then order songs by artist by ASC?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select

I am working on a music player and I'd like to list all of the songs sorted by artist going from A-Z (ASC). The information is stored in a table with *artist*, *file*, *song*, etc.

I tried using while loops to order first the artist by A-Z, then the songs by the artist A-Z, but that didn't work. I never completely understood any kind of loops, so help would be appreciated!

One of the queries I used was `SELECT * FROM musicinfo WHERE user='$user' ORDER BY artist ASC`.

Comment: is there error? what is not working in your query?

Comment: The query looks fine, what's the problem?

Comment: After I sort by artist, I want to sort ASC by filename, except somehow in a while loop? I don't know how to do it correctly, although the query will be `SELECT * FROM musicinfo WHERE artist='$artist' ORDER BY file ASC` (I believe)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

so you need multiple sort right? just add it on you `ORDER BY` clause.

```
SELECT * 
FROM   musicinfo 
WHERE  user = '$user' 
ORDER  BY artist ASC, file ASC
```

As a sidenote, the query is vulnerable with [`SQL Injection`](http://bobby-tables.com/) if the value(*s*) came from the outside. Please take a look at the article below to learn how to prevent from it. By using `PreparedStatements` you can get rid of using single quotes around values.

- [How to *prevent SQL injection* in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: So will it be like

"Arriving Somewhere But Not Here" by Porcupine Tree, then "Time Flies" by same artist, then "01 New Generation Slave" by "Riverside", then "Index" by "Steven Wilson"?

Comment: Just ran it through mysql, it worked! Wow, simple addition to my existing query and I would've had it. It's 2AM haha. Thanks!

Comment: No you can't sleep. First you have to reimplement your code in either PDO or MySQLi... :)